# Javascript event on form add fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I've got a rails app using bootstrap with a form page that has the option to add additional form fields. The tutorial from this [Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) heavily influenced this form page add fields feature. I have a need to watch the add fields so that I can hide a warning panel in the new well created. Here is the code that will not work(in coffeescript):

```
  $('#classifications_forms').on 'change', (event) ->
     container = $('.classifications_form').last()
     $('#premium-divide', container).hide()
```

Here is the code in jquery:

```
$('#classifications_forms').on('change', function(event) {
  var container;
  container = $('.classifications_form').last();
  return $('#premium-divide', container).hide();
});
```

I have tried an on click event for the add fields button, but it's late in the event watching as it will not hide the panel. If I hit the button a second time, it will hide the panel on the previously created well, so I know the code was working to hide the panel. My thinking is to hide the panel on the last well created, and I thought that a change on #classifications_forms would give me the event needed to hide the last well, but I guess its missing something on the event. What is missing above?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1w16jg96/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: can u provide a working sample to reproduce the isse (live-snippet/fiddle/bootply)? Also, your JS-code seems syntactically wrong to me.

Comment: Added the fiddle and added the jquery as I only had the coffescript. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was using bootstrap, I found a class to apply to the panel which took care of my problem:

```
.hidden
```